# Domain name for SSH

Tags: router, security, firewall, ssh

What is the purpose of a domain name to create SSH keys?

Before enabling SSH on firewall/router, we need to create domain name.

Why is it necessary to do that? What does a domain name do and how is it related to SSH? What role does it play in enabling SSH?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't necessary to create a domain name to create SSH keys.  The below syntax will allow you to generate RSA keys for SSH use without one.

```
router(config)#crypto key generate rsa general-keys label RSAKEY
```

Comment: so domain name is not necessary, its an optional one ya..

Comment: @satheesh91 Correct, it's not required if you label your own crypto keys.

Answer (score -1):

IP domain-name command is used to complete the "crypto key generate rsa command". Check out a couple of these [links](https://serverfault.com/questions/298656/why-does-cisco-ios-require-domain-name-to-be-set-before-ssh-keys-can-be-generate)

Comment: i want some real example kindly share it pls. still in confusion

Comment: NE encourages members to give full answers and discourages the use of [link answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). If you can expand on your answer a little more, please do.